# WooCommerce get order item single price (without quantity multiplication)

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm looking for a way to get the single price of an order item in WooCommerce. I've followed this post here and used the `get_price()` method but this method seems to be not available anymore:

[Woocommerce - Getting the order item price and quantity.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40711160/woocommerce-getting-the-order-item-price-and-quantity)

```
foreach ( $order_items as $order_item ) {
    error_log( $order_item->get_price() );
    error_log( print_r( $order_item, true ) );
}
```

> Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method
> WC_Order_Item_Product::get_price()

The problem is that I can't just get the product and read the normal price there because I need the price set during the order placement and a product price can be changed later a lot of times.

I've also printed out the whole order item to find the single price field there but found nothing:

```
[data:protected] => Array
    (
        [order_id] => 24
        [name] => Dings Teil
        [product_id] => 23
        [variation_id] => 0
        [quantity] => 2
        [tax_class] => 
        [subtotal] => 42.4
        [subtotal_tax] => 6.78
        [total] => 42.4
        [total_tax] => 6.78
        [taxes] => Array
            (
                [total] => Array
                    (
                        [6] => 6.784
                    )
                [subtotal] => Array
                    (
                        [6] => 6.784
                    )
            )
    )
```

So all in all I need the single price from my order item somehow. WooCommerce seems to have a way getting it in the order items view but I can't find the way they deal with this:

[image]

Because I'm writing a plugin, any WooCommerce changes are not a good idea at all.

**Update:**

Yes, I've also had the idea dividing the subtotal by the quantity but this may cause some rounding problems in the case my rounding is not 100% like the WooCommerce rounding.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The method `get_price()` is used by the `WC_Product` Class… Use the following instead:

```
foreach ( $order->get_items() as $item ) {
    $product = $item->get_product(); // Get the WC_Product Object
    $price   = $product->get_price();
    error_log( $price );
    error_log( print_r( $order_item, true ) );
}
```

It should better work.

---

You can also use the following (dividing item subtotal by quantity):

```
foreach ( $order->get_items() as $item ) {
    $quantity      = $item->get_quantity(); // Quantity
    $subtotal     = $item->get_subtotal(); // Line subtotal
    $subtotal_tax = $item->get_subtotal_tax(); // Line subtotal tax

    $price_excl_tax = $subtotal / $quantity;
    $price_incl_tax = ( $subtotal + $subtotal_tax ) / $quantity
    error_log( 'Price without tax: ' . $price_excl_tax );
    error_log( 'Price with tax: ' . $price_incl_tax );
}
```

Comment: Because the product price can change, I've decided to took the lower solution (dividing by quantity).

Comment: Do you know if there is a way getting cod costs? If yes, I would ask a question about this. I only know the get_fees() method but the costs are depending on the shop language which makes it very complex getting the right fee...

Comment: There is no COD cost, but for something much more clean and effective, you can clone COD payment gateway extending `WC_Payment_gateway` Class [as shown in this thread (in a custom plugin)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63787049/extending-woocommerce-cod-payment-gateway-in-a-plugin/63792485#63792485), see also [this related thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63986726/change-specific-payment-gateway-title-in-woocommerce/64000593#64000593)… Then you can make changes to this cloned payment gateway, to include a cost based on anything that you require, but this is something advanced.

Answer (score 2):

WooCommerce does this itself in the admin views for Orders:

```
$order->get_item_subtotal( $item, false, true )
```

Here is how you could adapt your code to get the item single price without quantity multiplication:

```
foreach ( $order_items as $order_item ) {
    $order = $order_item->get_order(); // Returns WC_Order object
    error_log( $order->get_item_subtotal( $order_item, false, true ) ); // Returns item price without multiplying by quantity.
}
```

See: woocommerce/includes/admin/meta-boxes/views/html-order-item.php